# how to set the speed of dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

first, i created a tab content in html using javascript and now, i transfer it to a drop-down content. My problem is, how can i set the speed of dropping content. Can you give me sample or idea how can i solve this problem. Thanks for the reply.

this my sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sample(){
if(document.getElementById("cute").style.display=="none"){
document.getElementById.("cute").style.display="";
 document.getElementById.("ugly").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById.("good").style.display="none";
}
}

function samplez(){
if(document.getElementById("good").style.display=="none"){
document.getElementById.("good").style.display="";
 document.getElementById.("cute").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById.("ugly").style.display="none";
}
}

function samplex(){
if(document.getElementById("ugly").style.display=="none"){
document.getElementById.("ugly").style.display="";
 document.getElementById.("cute").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById.("good").style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
</head>
```

here is the body code:

```
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false; sample();">Sample</a></li>
 <p id ="cute" style = "display:none;">This is sample 1.</p>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false; samplex();">Sample x</a></li>
 <p id ="good" style = "display:none;">This is sample 2.</p>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false; samplez();">Sample z</a></li>
 <p id ="ugly" style = "display:none;">This is sample 3.</p>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

my question is how to set the speed of drop-down view if you click anything of the link.

Comment: Just a thought, jQuery has plenty of very easy to use animation functions built in. That said, Im not really familiar with how difficult (or not) it is in pure JS.

Comment: As Foo_Chow suggested, jQuery would work great for this. If you don't want to use it, you could always take a look at the code and find out how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

html5 animation might help， [check more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)
Or, you can use **setTimeout** to increase the height value of css every 1ms(what ever you like) to have the animation.

```
var dropDown = function() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("xxx");    
  var h = ele.style.height;
  ele.style.height = parseInt(h.substring(0, h.length-2)) + 2 + "px";
  setTimeout(dropDown, 1);
};
setTimeout(dropDown, 1);
```

Comment: check the code, it shows the setTimeout usage, you need make some changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout. More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp